# Fate of Jim in The Marksman

Tags: plot-explanation, ending, the-marksman

In the movie the Marksman we know that Jim is shot on the farm. At the end of the movie after dropping off Miguel with his relatives in Chicago he gets on a city bus and sits down. The movie ends at that point. What is the fate of Jim?

Answer (score 1):

We don't know but the implication is that he dies.

[**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Marksman_(2021_film))

> The pair eventually reach Miguel's family in Chicago, and Hanson boards a city bus and closes his eyes. **It is implied he dies from his injuries.**